# Firebase Retrieve Data from reference (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and am setting up so that a user can create an exercise set by selecting from a collection of exercises. here is my db:[image]

This is my code:

```
struct fbExercise: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var musclegroup: String
    var instructions: String
}

struct fbExerciseSet: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var reps: Int
    var weight: Int
    var time: Int
    var dateCompleted: Date
    var exercise: fbExercise
   // var workout: fbWorkout
}
```

and my function to get the data:

```
@Published var exerciseSetList = [fbExerciseSet]()    
func getExerciseSets(){

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("exerciseSet").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if error == nil {
            // check error
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.exerciseSetList = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                        let exerciseRef = d["exercise"] as? DocumentReference

                        return fbExerciseSet(
                            id: d.documentID,
                            reps: d["reps"] as? Int ?? 1,
                            weight: d["weight"] as? Int ?? 1,
                            time: d["time"] as? Int ?? 1,
                            dateCompleted: d["date"] as? Date ?? Date(),
                            exercise: d["exercise"] as! fbExercise
                        )
                   }
              }
          }
      }
```

I am having trouble retrieving the data in fbExerciseSet. It keeps returning as an empty list. I think I should be using the DocumentReference for retrieving the exercise but I'm not really sure how. When I test without the exercise property on exercise set it retrieves the other properties of reps, time, and weight no problem, I just can't retrieve the exercise within the exerciseset. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here, or what your question is.  Please edit the question to explain what's not working the way you expect with the code you have now.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited the question. I am not able to retrieve the exercise property of the exercise set

Comment: Firestore queries are asynchronous and return immediately before the callback is invoked.  You're probably using `fbExerciseSet` before the query is complete and it's been populated with data.  Add some logging to see the order in which all of your code is executing.

Comment: That is a DocumentReference not a fbExercise from the reference you can get document again